# Sort solutions in maxima?

Tags: arrays, sorting, maxima

Consider that I get this output in maxima:

```
b : solve([ans,ans2],[x,y]);    
float(b);
    [[x=0.0,y=%r11],[x=-5.0,y=0.0],[x=1.0422311,y=0.537285*%i],[x=-0.940313,y=0.537285*%i],[x=-5.1019178,y=0.537285*
    %i],[x=1.0422311,y=-0.537285],[x=-0.940313,y=-0.537285],[x=-5.1019178,y=-0.537285],[x=1.0422311,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=-
    0.940313,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=-5.1019178,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=1.0422311,y=0.537285],[x=-0.940313,y=0.537285],[x=-5.1019178,y
    =0.537285]]
```

How can I sort the solutions and get only the ones on the domain -2 < x < 2, and -2 < y < 2 ?

I've looked for this solution quite a bit and it would be really helpful, since I could find what I'm looking for without any "noise".

Could it be something I write in the "solve" command brackets?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sublist`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/en/maxima_5.html#IDX157)

```
b: [[x=0.0,y=%r11],[x=-5.0,y=0.0],[x=1.0422311,y=0.537285*%i],[x=-0.940313,y=0.537285*%i],[x=-5.1019178,y=0.537285*
    %i],[x=1.0422311,y=-0.537285],[x=-0.940313,y=-0.537285],[x=-5.1019178,y=-0.537285],[x=1.0422311,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=-
    0.940313,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=-5.1019178,y=-0.537285*%i],[x=1.0422311,y=0.537285],[x=-0.940313,y=0.537285],[x=-5.1019178,y
    =0.537285]];

filter(s):= block([x: assoc(x, s), y: assoc(y, s)],
  featurep(x, real) and featurep(y, real) and x>-2 and x<2 and y>-2 and y<2);

sublist(b, 'filter);
```

Returns:

```
(%o9) [[x = 1.0422311, y = - 0.537285], [x = - 0.940313, y = - 0.537285], 
                 [x = 1.0422311, y = 0.537285], [x = - 0.940313, y = 0.537285]]
```